# Converting data javascript

Tags: javascript, date

In a for loop, I want to get different dates for every item. I had implemented the following and it was working fine:

```
//This retrieves the right dates:
result.date = offer.get("createdAt");
result.updated = exchange.get("updatedAt");
result.expiration = exchange.get("expirationDate");
```

I was getting:

```
2017-09-01T20:33:35.245Z
2017-08-01T19:07:15.510Z
2017-07-28T19:43:11.590Z
```

As I want to convert to date format and get only month, date, year and time, I implement this:

```
//This brings the same date every time;
var date = Date(offer.get("createdAt"));
result.date = date.substr(4, 17);
result.shortDate = result.date.substr(4, 11);

var expiration = Date(exchange.get("expirationDate"));
result.expiration = expiration.substr(4, 11);

var updated = Date(exchange.get("updatedAt"));
result.updated = updated.substr(4, 11);
```

But it keeps bringing the same date for every element:

```
Sep 02 2017 18:08
Sep 02 2017 18:08 (this should be a different date)
Sep 02 2017 18:08 (this should be a different date)
```

I don't what I am missing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The value returned by [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) is implementation dependent, so there is no guarantee that using it with a fixed *substr* component will provide a consistent result. See [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, use the following code instead:

```
var date = new Date(offer.get("createdAt"));
result.date = date.toString().substr(4, 17);
result.shortDate = result.date.substr(4, 11);

var expiration = new Date(exchange.get("expirationDate"));
result.expiration = expiration.toString().substr(4, 11);

var updated = new Date(exchange.get("updatedAt"));
result.updated = updated.toString().substr(4, 11);
```

So, the issue is you are not using Date() with the new keyword.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment as your post isn't really a solution. It's a recommendation to use a plugin with no detail of how this will be useful or how to impliment your recommendation to achieve the OPs expected outcome.

Comment: Sure, I was actually working on the code. I will edit the answer to add the jsfiddle in just a while or remove the answer if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Then you should plan your answer before posting otherwise you will have comments like this. Not my fault you decided to post a recommendation/incomplete answer.

Comment: @Gabriela, I have edited the answer. the new code should give you the right answers. Please check.

Comment: It works!! It was not only "new" but also converting toString. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The value returned by [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) is implementation dependent, so there is no guarantee that this will give a consistent result. See [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` keyword before `Date()`, without it, you're just creating today's date, then convert them to strings in order to use `substr` with them :

```js
var result = {};

var date = new Date("2017-09-01T20:33:35.245Z").toString();
result.date = date.substr(4, 17);
result.shortDate = result.date.substr(4, 11);

var expiration = new Date("2017-08-01T19:07:15.510Z").toString();
result.expiration = expiration.substr(4, 11);

var updated = new Date("2017-07-28T19:43:11.590Z").toString();
result.updated = updated.substr(4, 11);

console.log(result);
```